# How does dimensionality of network topology affect self organising maps?

Tags: neural-networks, self-organizing-maps

I'm pretty new to self organising maps (SOMs). From reading around a bit, it seems like most implemetations use a 2D grid for the SOM network structure (or less often a 1D grid). This is nice, cause it's easy to visualise, but is there any particular reason why barely anyone uses 3D grids, etc? In particular, how does a higher dimensional network topology affect computational difficulty, results, and interpretation of results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not much to say about computational difficulties, since I haven't used a 3D map with real data. I don't think it will impose a great overhead. You just have to add one more dimension in the distance and neighborhood functions.

Theoretically a 3D map will produce better clustering results because it will have a more flexible grid to adapt to the dataset but visualization is crucial in SOM. Human interpretation is based on visualization. If you could build a fancy tool for 3D visualization and exploration of the map then you could go with this option. If you are doing machine interpretation then you could go with the 3D. Again adding one more dimension wouldn’t bring so much trouble.

Check [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b3nG4c2NECI), the 3d part, to see how a 2d grid adapts to a 3 dimensional input space. Now imaging if you had a 3d grid at this dataset. The adaptation would ofcourse be better.

From a quick search I found also [this paper](http://www.iaeng.org/publication/WCE2012/WCE2012_pp696-701.pdf) which is relevant to your question.